# Create a price range from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to upper limit of the price filter should be based product prices

As you can see this o/p i am getting different price ranges for different products.
I want to have just a single array in "options" key.

That will have highest upper limit for example

desired o/p =

```
[options] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => 0-500
                        [value] => 0_500
                        [count] => // This will be total count
                    )
```

Current o/p

```
Array
(
    [label] => Price
    [count] => 5
    [attribute_code] => price
    [options] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => 0-100
                    [value] => 0_100
                    [count] => 2208
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => 100-200
                    [value] => 100_200
                    [count] => 338
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [label] => 200-300
                    [value] => 200_300
                    [count] => 16
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [label] => 300-400
                    [value] => 300_400
                    [count] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [label] => 400-500
                    [value] => 400_500
                    [count] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

need guidance how it can be done ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Loop over all options, findest the smallest lower boundary, and findet the largest upper one. The combination of those, is your new label/value. And the count you can simply sum up while you're looping over the items. And then you just replace the existing `options` array with a new one, that you just put this one desired result element into.

Comment: I have tried end($prices['options'] but it returns the 


Array
(
    [label] => 400-500
    [value] => 400_500
    [count] => 1
)

Comment: Is just picking the last element what you wanted to do? No? Then _of course_ `end` doesn't do the job.

Comment: findest the smallest lower boundary, and findet the largest upper one. The combination of those, is your new label/value.

this seems tricky could you please advice how it can be done ?

Comment: Well that already _was_ supposed to be my advice on how to do it ... What part in particular are you having a problem with?

Comment: I am not sure how to findest the smallest lower boundary, and findet the largest upper one in loop ?

Comment: If you don't know how to instruct the computer to solve the problem - then think about how _you_ would do it, if you had to do it manually. If I gave you a handful of differently sized pebbles, and asked you to return the smallest one to me - what would you do? You start by picking the first one, and comparing it to the second. If the first is the smaller one of those two, you keep that one - else you keep the other. And then you keep doing that, until you went through all of them ...

Comment: Of course you can also just go and put all lower boundaries into an array first, and all the upper ones into a second - and then use `min`/`max` on those. Different levels of "sophistication" almost always exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_sum(array_column($prices['options'], 'count'))` to retrieve the total counts from each of the price options.

Use `array_column($prices['options'], 'value');` to extract the values from the array, that can be used to sort or sum the values of.

Sort the prices by the values from lowest to highest using `array_multisort($values, SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL, $prices['options']);`

Extract the highest and lowest values from the sorted array, by using `reset()` and `end()` of the resulting sorted array.

Alternatively in PHP 7.3+ use `array_key_first()` and `array_key_last()` respectively.

```
$values[array_key_first($values)];
$values[array_key_last($values)];
```

Use `explode('_')` on the highest and lowest values and retrieve the indexed offset of `[0]` or `[1]` of the first or last position of the separated values.

```
$counts = array_sum(array_column($prices['options'], 'count'));

$values = array_column($prices['options'], 'value');
array_multisort($values, SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL);

$lowest = explode('_', reset($values))[0];
$highest = explode('_', end($values))[1];

/* PHP 7.3+
$lowest = explode('_', $values[array_key_first($values)])[0];
$highest = explode('_', $values[array_key_last($values)])[1];
*/

$prices['options'] =  [
    'label' => $lowest . '-' . $highest,
    'value' => $lowest . '_' . $highest,
    'count' => $counts
];

var_export($prices['options']);
```

Result: https://3v4l.org/PmXg3 
PHP 7.3+: https://3v4l.org/iTbcq

```
array (
  'label' => '0-500',
  'value' => '0_500',
  'count' => 2564,
)
```

---

### Ambiguous Ranges

In the event you have ambiguous ranges, where the upper and lower bounds can be the same, EG: `100-200` and `100-600` or `100-600` and `200-600`. Each lower and upper value would need to be extracted without needing to rely on sorting.

PHP 7.2 + Example: https://3v4l.org/a8BCL#v7.2.34

```
$counts = array_sum(array_column($prices['options'], 'count'));

$values = [];
foreach ($prices['options'] as $priceOption) {
    [$values[], $values[]] = explode('_', $priceOption['value']);
}
$lower = min($values);
$upper = max($values);

$prices['options'] = [
    'label' => $lower . '-' . $upper,
    'value' => $lower . '_' . $upper,
    'count' => $counts,
];
```

Comment: This works on the data OP has given, because the ranges go up by 100 every time. However if there is a value `100-600` in the above, this will contain the lowest an the highest at the same time. In that case you'll get the lowest (100) but not the highest.

Comment: @Michel updated for ambiguous ranges. Though I am fairly certain that scenario would have been answered on SO before. Will see if there is a duplicate.

Comment: I suspect this whole question can be answered by searching on SO. The problem for many people - especially beginners and non-English speakers - is: what to search for? You can have the right idea how to solve it an still get stuck if you don't know certain functions exist. Should be a seperate stack-page for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

**SUM [count]**

`array_column()` : extract all count from $prices['options']

`array_sum()` : add them up.

```
$count = array_sum(array_column($prices['options'], 'count'));
```

**EXTRACT all MIN and MAX values**

`array_map()` : walk $prices['options'] and apply the given function

`explode('_',$option['value'])` :: split the string in a lower and upper part.

return the values to `$minmax`

```
$minmax = array_map(
   function($option){
     $split=explode('_',$option['value']);
     return [(int)$split[0],(int)$split[1]];
     },
   $prices['options']
 );
```

**EXTRACT the MIN** column from `$minmax` and get the lowest number: `min()`

```
$min=min(array_column($minmax,0));
```

**EXTRACT the MAX** column from `$minmax` and get the highest number: `max()`

```
$max=max(array_column($minmax,1));


$prices['options'] = [
    'label' => $min . '-' . $max,
    'value' => $min . '_' . $max,
    'count' => $count
];
```

[An example](https://3v4l.org/GqI2U)